# Why does white phosphorous exhibit chemiluminescence?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

My work - I only know that chemiluminescence means glowing in dark.

Comment: Long story short, nobody really knows.

Comment: Oh! I thought that there was a reason to explain it.

Comment: You might go with _"white phosphorus oxidizes in the air and emits light in the process"_. This is true, but does not really explain anything.

Comment: Actually, I got something from a source .

Comment: Chemiluminescence is the emission of cold light as a result of a chemical reaction. In a chemiluminescent reaction, reactive intermediates are formed which enter electronically excited states. Subsequent transition back to ground state is accompanied by a release of energy in form of light.

Comment: Sounds good. Same as I said plus a few smart words and hand-waving. Yes, I guess this is what they want from you. Anyway, nobody really knows what is that intermediate.

Comment: Among the excimers that undergo emission the most likely are PO2 and HPO, the role of the latter indicated by deuterium effects. In all cases the luminescence of white phosphorus does requires oxygen, and is a consequence of a reaction.  This should already be useful to you, as it is not evident if it was clear what chemiluminescence is (emission of light as follow up of a chemical reaction, which is not the case of fluorescence and phosphorescence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://www.chemistryandlight.eu/index.php/chemiluminescence/):

> The best-known and first well-documented example of deliberately
>   induced, man-made chemiluminescence was the discovery of elemental
>   phosphorus by a German alchemist H. Brand. **The waxy white phosphorus
>   is slowly oxidized at room temperature giving off faint greenish glow.
>   The formation of excited reactive intermediate $\ce{(PO)2}$ and
>   $\ce{HPO}$ is responsible for the green glow.**

That's where the term *phosphorescence* come from.